# React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I'm currently building a test app using React Native. The Image module thus far has been working fine.

For example, if I had an image named `avatar`, the below code snippet works fine.

```
<Image source={require('image!avatar')} />
```

But if I change it to a dynamic string, I get

```
<Image source={require('image!' + 'avatar')} />
```

I get the error:

```
Requiring unknown module "image!avatar". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.
```

Obviously, this is a contrived example, but dynamic image names are important. Does React Native not support dynamic image names?

[image: React native error with dynamic image name]

Comment: I encountered similar problem with Vue, answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working/60970936#60970936

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation under the section "[Static Resources](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources)":

> The only allowed way to refer to an image in the bundle is to literally write require('image!name-of-the-asset') in the source.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('image!my-icon')} />

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('image!' + icon)} />

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('image!my-icon-active') : require('image!my-icon-inactive');
<Image source={icon} />
```

However you also need to remember to add your images to an xcassets bundle in your app in Xcode, though it seems from your comment you've done that already.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#adding-static-resources-to-your-app-using-images-xcassets

Comment: where should I add images , i am using react native for android,in the drawable folder?

Comment: The link above is incorrect, the article is now at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Comment: hi , how to do if I have hundreds of images need to require?

Comment: @chanjianyi I am on the same situation :-(

Comment: "Require" is not working on IOS devices for me. Any ideia why?

Comment: How on earth is this solution "dynamic"?

Answer (score 90):

**RELEVANT IF YOU HAVE KNOWN IMAGES (URLS):**

The way I hacked my way through this problem:

I created a file with an object that stored the image and the name of the image:

```
export const ANIMAL_IMAGES = {
  dog: {
    imgName: 'Dog', 
    uri: require('path/to/local/image')
  },
  cat: {
    imgName: 'Cat on a Boat', 
    uri: require('path/to/local/image')
  }
}
```

Then I imported the object into the component where I want to use it and just do my conditional rendering like so:

```
import { ANIMAL_IMAGES } from 'path/to/images/object';

let imgSource = null;

if (condition === 'cat') {
  imgSource = ANIMAL_IMAGES.cat.uri;
}

<Image source={imgSource} />
```

I know it is not the most efficient way but it is definitely a workaround.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Neat solution to handle a known set of images

Comment: @WalterMonecke: am getting integer value if we do like this

Comment: A similar approach using this ANIMAL_IMAGES object:
`/* where condition === 'cat' or another known key */`
`imgSource = ANIMAL_IMAGES[condition]?.uri ?? require('path/to/default/img');`

Answer (score 81):

This worked for me :

I made a custom image component which takes in a boolean to check if the image is from web or is being passed from a local folder.

```
// In index.ios.js after importing the component
<CustomImage fromWeb={false} imageName={require('./images/logo.png')}/>

// In CustomImage.js which is my image component
<Image style={styles.image} source={this.props.imageName} />
```

If you see the code, instead of using one of these:

```
// NOTE: Neither of these will work
source={require('../images/'+imageName)} 
var imageName = require('../images/'+imageName)
```

I'm just sending the entire `require('./images/logo.png')` as a prop. **It works!**

Comment: This answer deserves more credit. It absolutely works when you declare the require statement and pass as a prop. Thank you so much for your simple explanation, I only wish others would be as clear.

Comment: The prop thing work wonders. That should be stated on the official docs.

Comment: ```class CustomImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={this.props.imageName} resizeMode="contain" style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }} />
    );
  }
}```
```<CustomImage fromWeb={false} imageName={require(`../../images/phone-${item.status}.png`)} />```

Comment: In the parent Component I have            `<CustomImage fromWeb={false} imageName={require(`../../assets/icons/${el.img}.png`)} />`   and this in the child component `class CustomImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={this.props.imageName} resizeMode="contain" style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }} />
    );
  }
}`

Comment: Do I still have to add the images to xCode?

Comment: @BK7 It seems that i works for you because you hardcoded the URL in the CustomImage tag. However, mine is dynamic.

Comment: @WalterMonecke I think you're right, I just checked for dynamic URLs, it's not working. You need not add images separately to Xcode as react-native link will take care of it.

Comment: Hi, dear @BK7 I tried your answer and it didn't work [check this](https://pastebin.com/BYSh6mkw), what did I missing? could you help with a  check? have been stuck here :D

Comment: Hi @armnotstrong, It doesn't work because you're passing a variable to the require method, i.e require(item). unfortunately, it works only if you pass hardcoded urls i.e the string as quoted in the above example. Still couldn't figure out why that happens. 

I'd recommend you upload these files in AWS S3 or firebase hosting etc.. and use the uri method of getting images instead.

Comment: @BK7 thanks for replying that, and I have chosen to input all those file paths with my bare hand, this is insane and hope reactnative could fix that :-(

Comment: @armnotstrong Hopefully.

Comment: Pure genius, this is exactly what I was searching for :)

Comment: this doesn't help me with the problem of not being able to use concatenated strings in the "require"

Comment: This should be the preferred answer

Comment: I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time. Thank you very much this method works

Answer (score 47):

If you're looking for a way to create a list by looping through a JSON array of your images and descriptions for example, this will work for you.

1. Create a file (to hold our JSON database) e.g ProfilesDB.js:

```js
const Profiles = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Peter Parker',
    src: require('../images/user1.png'),
    age: '70',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Barack Obama',
    src: require('../images/user2.png'),
    age: '19',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Hilary Clinton',
    src: require('../images/user3.png'),
    age: '50',
  },
];

export default Profiles;
```

2. Then import the data in our component and loop through the list using a FlatList:

```js
import Profiles from './ProfilesDB.js';

<FlatList
  data={Profiles}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <View>
      <Image source={item.src} />
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I am creating a local "data" file in my app and I needed to access the images. I have tried 

<Image source={require(item.img)} />

But it was not working so after trying the solution you provided it worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: if there is  more image files then what would be the logic to achive that? I can't write 
 code manually for all those 50 images.  I was able to list out all images and export all but it was node js code.

Comment: @CrackerKSR, you're right. This solution usually works best for a few images.

Answer (score 23):

First, create a file with image required - React native images must be loaded this way.

assets/index.js

```
export const friendsandfoe = require('./friends-and-foe.png'); 
export const lifeanddeath = require('./life-and-death.png'); 
export const homeandgarden = require('./home-and-garden.png');
```

Now import all your assets

App.js

```
import * as All  from '../../assets';
```

You can now use your image as an interpolated value where imageValue (coming in from backend) is the same as named local file ie: 'homeandgarden':

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={All[`${imageValue}`]}></Image>
```

Comment: No worries! Couldn't find a good solution on here so came up with my own one :) Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 21):

> As the [React Native Documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html), all your images sources needs to be loaded before compiling your bundle

So another way you can use dynamic images it's using a switch statement. Let's say you want to display a different avatar for a different character, you can do something like this:

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = { avatar: "" }

  get avatarImage() {
    switch (this.state.avatar) {
      case "spiderman":
        return require('./spiderman.png');
      case "batman":
        return require('./batman.png');
      case "hulk":
        return require('./hulk.png');
      default:
        return require('./no-image.png');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Image source={this.avatarImage} />
  }
}
```

Check the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/dynamic-images

[image]

Also, remember if your image it's online you don't have any problems, you can do:

```js
let superhero = "spiderman";

<Image source={{ uri: `https://some-website.online/${superhero}.png` }} />
```

Answer (score 12):

**Important Part here:**
We cannot concat the image name inside the require like [require('item'+vairable+'.png')]

***Step 1: We create a ImageCollection.js file with the following collection of image properties***

```
ImageCollection.js
================================
export default images={
    "1": require("./item1.png"),
    "2": require("./item2.png"),
    "3": require("./item3.png"),
    "4": require("./item4.png"),
    "5": require("./item5.png")
}
```

***Step 2: Import image in your app and manipulate as necessary***

```
class ListRepoApp extends Component {

    renderItem = ({item }) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item number :{item}</Text>
            <Image source={Images[item]}/>
        </View>
    );

    render () {
        const data = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
        return (
            <FlatList data={data} renderItem={this.renderItem}/>
        )
    }
}

export default ListRepoApp;
```

If you want a detailed explanation you could follow the link below
Visit https://www.thelearninguy.com/react-native-require-image-using-dynamic-names

Courtesy : https://www.thelearninguy.com

Comment: here is the best solution I found

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
<Image source={{uri: 'imagename'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
```

to show image.

from:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources

Answer (score 5):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

class Images extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
           images: {
                './assets/RetailerLogo/1.jpg': require('../../../assets/RetailerLogo/1.jpg'),
                './assets/RetailerLogo/2.jpg': require('../../../assets/RetailerLogo/2.jpg'),
                './assets/RetailerLogo/3.jpg': require('../../../assets/RetailerLogo/3.jpg')
            }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {  images } = this.state 
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
                            resizeMode="contain"
                            source={ images['assets/RetailerLogo/1.jpg'] }
                            style={styles.itemImg}
                        />
     </View>
  )}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To dynamic image using require

```
this.state={
       //defualt image
       newimage: require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room3.png'),
       randomImages=[
         {
            image:require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room1.png')
          },
         {
            image:require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room2.png')
          }
        ,
         {
            image:require('../../../src/assets/group/kids_room3.png')
          }
        
        
        ]

}
```

when press the button-(i select image random number betwenn 0-2))

```
let setImage=>(){
//set new dynamic image 
this.setState({newimage:this.state.randomImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
})
}
```

view

```
<Image
        style={{  width: 30, height: 30 ,zIndex: 500 }}
        
        source={this.state.newimage}
      />
```

Answer (score 3):

Say if you have an application that has similar functionality as that of mine. Where your app is mostly offline and you want to render the Images one after the other. Then below is the approach that worked for me in React Native version 0.60.

1. First create a folder named **Resources/Images** and place all your images there.
2. Now create a file named **Index.js** (at Resources/Images) which is responsible for Indexing all the images in the **Resources/Images** folder.

> const Images = {
> 'image1': require('./1.png'),
> 'image2': require('./2.png'),
> 'image3': require('./3.png')
> }

3. Now create a Component named ImageView in your choice of folder. One can create functional, class or constant component. I have used the Const component. This file is responsible for returning the Image depending on the Index.

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import { Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
> import Images from './Index';
> const ImageView = ({ index }) => {
>     return (
>         <Image
>             source={Images['image' + index]}
>         />
>     )
> }
> export default ImageView;
> ```

4. Now from the component wherever you want to render the Static Images dynamically, just use the ImageView component and pass the index.

   **< ImageView index={this.qno + 1} />**

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I'm going to add this here as I've found this question, whilst searching for a solution.  The docs allow for a uri: 'Network Image'

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-images

For me I got images working dynamically with this

```
<Image source={{uri: image}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <StyledInput text="NAME" imgUri={require('../assets/userIcon.png')} ></StyledInput> 

<Image
            source={this.props.imgUri}
            style={{
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
```

in my case i tried so much but finally it work  **StyledInput component name**
image inside the StyledInput if you still not understand let me know

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a simple and truly dynamic solution to the problem if you have a bigger no of files.**

-*Won't work for Expo Managed*

*Although the question is old I think this is the simpler solution and might be helpful. But I beg a pardon for any terminological mistakes, correct me please if I do any.*

INSTEAD OF USING **REQUIRE** WE CAN USE THE **URI** WITH **NATIVE APP ASSETS** FOR ANDROID (AND/OR iOS). **HERE WE WILL DISCUSS ABOUT ANDROID ONLY**

*URI can easily be manipulated as per the requirement but normally it's used for network/remote assets only but works for local and native assets too. Whereas require can not be used for dynamic file names and dirs*

**STEPS**

1. Open `android/app/src/main/assets` folder from your `App.js` or `index.js` containing directory, if the `assets` folder doesn't exist create one.
2. Make a folder named `images` or any `NAME` of your choice inside `assets`, and paste all the images there.
3. Create a file named `react-native.config.js` in the main app folder containing `App.js` or `index.js`.
4. Add these lines to the new js file:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/'],
};
```

at the place of `YOUR_FOLDER_NAME` use the newly created folder's name `images` or any given `NAME`

5. Now run `npx react-native link` in your terminal from main app folder, this will link/add the assets folder in the android bundle. Then rebuild the debug app.
6. From now on you can access all the files from inside `android/app/src/main/assets` in your react-native app.
   For example:

```
<Image
   style={styles.ImageStyle}
   source={{ uri: 'asset:/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME/img' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + '.png' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a constant where you save the image path including require, then in source put the name of that constant.

```
const image = condition ? require("../img/image1.png") : require('../img/image2.png');

<Image source={image} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a thumb rule. One `require` for every image.

So if you want to dynamically load 20 images, make sure you have written `require`  keyword 20 times explicitely.

Answer (score -1):

You should use an object for that.

For example, let's say that I've made an AJAX request to an API and it returns an image link that I'll save to state as `imageLink`:

`source={{uri: this.state.imageLink}}`

Comment: for dynamic image path links, this doesn't work:

`var img = "../img/icons/"+img_name+"_selected.png";

<br/>
<Image source={{uri: img}} resizeMode={'contain'} />`

Comment: a hack for this, if you know all the img_name variants would be to go this way:
`var images = { 
'first': require('../first.png'),
'second': require('../second.png')
}
<Image source={{uri:images[img_name]}} resizeMode={'contain'} />`

Comment: Please be warned that for @GabrielLupu 's suggestion: You are allocating all of the images in the memory by this way. It depends on the number of images and their sizes however you will likely experience out of memory errors.