# Rendering a random card image: "Requiring unknown module"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to generate a random card image - depending on the string returned from this.generateRandomCard - but I'm getting the following error:

"Requiring unknown module "./card_images/7S.png". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install".

Note: Using require('./card_images/7S.png') works.

Here is my code:

```
render: function() {
  var card = require('./card_images/' + this.generateRandomCard() + '.png');
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{this.generateRandomCard()}</Text>
      <Image source={card}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names

see this link about dynamic requiring https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should randomise it in another way!
for example like this:

```
//define a list of images in component constructor
this.rImages = [require('random/image1.png'),require('random/image2.png'), ... etc]
```

Then in render function

```
//generate random integer between 0 and rImages.length
var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.rImages.length)
var rImage = this.rImages[randomInt]
<Image source={rImage}/>
```

Comment: I have 52 image variations.. Is there no way to shorten it?

Comment: for now it look like this is your best way to get it working. May be they fix it later ...

Comment: Quick update, I got it working. Thanks for the help!