# Vue 1.0 src binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

It doesn't work. Why?

```
<img v-if="item.foto.src" v-bind:src="item.foto.src" width="{{item.foto.width}}" height="{{item.foto.height}}" />
```

This causes an error in browser, although the image is displayed

```
   <img v-if="item.foto.src" src="/{{item.foto.src}}" width="{{item.foto.width}}" height="{{item.foto.height}}" />
```

%7B%7Bitem.foto.src%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js dynamic images not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The first one would not produce a 404 (if the path was correct, you're missing the `/`), the second one would.

You'd need to do:

```
<img :src="'/' + item.foto.src">
```

Comment: This answer should work, but there could be some issues if you are using webpack and serving images via webpack.