# How to show pdf with iframe in vue.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a vue.js webapp, I want to show an PDF in an iframe in the app, but it is not taking the path from the `assets` folder. Here is my code:

```
<iframe :src="getPDFPath()" style="width: 100vw;height: 100%;border: none;">
  Oops! an error has occurred.
</iframe>
```

Here is the `getPDFPath` method:

```
getPDFPath () {
   return '../../assets/my.pdf'
}
```

But this did not work and gives following error:

> Cannot GET /assets/my.pdf

However result of `{{ getPDFPath() }}` is : `../../assets/my.pdf`.

As I am using webpack, I also tried following, which also did not work:

```
getPDFPath () {
  var files = require.context('../../assets/', false)
  return files('./my.pdf')
}
```

This gives me following error:

> ./src/assets/my.pdf
>
> Module parse failed: >/Users/abc/work/codes/vue/src/assets/my.pdf 
>   Unexpected token (1:0)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

However above code works for images, as I have earlier answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40493036/1610034).

Comment: What happened when you were returning  `'../../assets/my.pdf'` string?

Comment: @SLYcee No, I think "()" is needed

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I have added the error in the question.

Comment: So you return `'../../assets/my.pdf'` but the error says `'/assets/my.pdf'`? Also, is the result same if you do {{ getPDFPath() }} just above the `<iframe>` ?

Comment: Do you want a simple reference to the pdf ? is it available via http directly? Can you use an absolute path?

Comment: I want to just show it in an iframe as part of the page, I have a copy of it, which I am putting in assets folder. I can serve images from this path.

Comment: Images and css could have been handled by webpack loaders. Not sure but because in the error the path is different so my guess is to try some other file like a docx or csv? If you can check the `__dirname` of the file in which you have the iframe?

Answer (score 2):

1 template

```
<iframe :src="pdfsrc" style="width: 100%;height: 300px; border: none;">
Oops! an error has occurred.
</iframe>
```

2 script

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    pdfsrc: null
  }),
  methods: {
    getPDFPath () {
      return axios
      .get('/sample-3pp.pdf', {
        responseType: "blob"
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Success", response);
        const blob = new Blob([response.data]);
        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        this.pdfsrc = objectUrl;
      })
     .catch(console.error); //
    } 
    created() {
        this.getPDFPath();
    }
}
</script>
```