# Generate dynamic img paths in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Relevant codepen](https://codepen.io/modermo/pen/PJjyXr?editors=1010)

I'm trying to generate dynamic image paths, but I'm missing something. For one reason or another, the method isn't executing on the `src` attribute in the `img` tags.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="app">

  <component v-bind:fruits="fruits" is="fruits-list"></component>

</div>

<template id="fruits-template">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="fruit in fruits">
        {{ fruit }}
        <img src="imgName(fruit)" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is the relevant JS:

```
Vue.component('fruits-list', {
  template:'#fruits-template',
  props: ['fruits'],
  methods: {
    imgName: function(fruit){
      var imgPath = 'assets/images/' + fruit + '.jpg';
      return imgPath;
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fruits: ['apple','pear','strawberry', 'peach']
    }
  }
})
```

I also did try binding the `src` to the `img` tag like :

```
<img :src="getImageUrl(fruit)" />
```

But that causes nothing to render at all. Is it better here to use a method or computed properties in an instance like this?

Comment: Where have you defined the getImageUrl method?

Comment: Using a method should work well. Try referring to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out in the html:

```
<img v-bind:src=imgName(fruit) />
```

When I change that in your pen, I see a failed request to this URL, and similar for the other fruits:

`Request URL:https://codepen.io/boomerang/iFrameKey-9b0f86ca-8c55-3b83-2d9c-3367ada2ac69/assets/images/apple.jpg`

Are there images for those fruits where you expect them to be? I changed the `imgName` method to the following and the image for the apple loads inside the pen:

```
imgName: function(fruit){
  if (fruit === 'apple') {
    return 'https://bestapples.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/apple-varieties.jpg'
  } else {
    var imgPath = 'assets/images/' + fruit + '.jpg';
    return imgPath;        
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey, yeah the images aren't meant to actually render in the pen. I just needed to figure out how to generate the image path. This works, so thanks :)