# Vue.js dynamic image paths not loading

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to load images dynamically within a single file component, but I'm getting an error that the module cannot be found. I think I'm trying to do the same thing as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I used the [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) to set up my project.

Here's the relevant markup in my template:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'JobsDetail', params: { slug: job.slug } }">
    <span class="icon">
        <img :src="getIconPath(job.slug)"/>
    </span>
    {{ job.title }}
</router-link>
```

And the function I'm trying to get the image from:

```
methods: {
    getIconPath (iconName) {
        const icons = require.context('../assets/', false, /\.png$/)
        return iconName ? icons(`./${iconName}.png`) : ''
    }
}
```

I have the images in the `/src/assets/` directory. The error I'm getting in the browser console is:

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './some-icon.png'."`

I'm not sure if this is a webpack config issue, or a problem with the getIconPath function. Anything help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is the file (path) that you have that JS code?

Comment: @acdcjunior this is all inside of a single file component located in `/src/components/JobList.vue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering your JavaScript code is at `/src/components/JobList.vue` and your images are at `/src/assets/`, use as follows:

```js
methods: {
    getIconPath (iconName) {
        return iconName ? require(`../assets/${iconName}`) : ''
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try it hardcoded? Some file you are sure it exists, like `/src/assets/my-icon.png` you do hardcoded like: `<img :src="getIconPath('my-icon.png')"/>`.

Comment: If it doesnt work, canyou paste the whole stack trace (not just the first line)? It contains important info.

Comment: Got it working from your suggestion to try the hard coded icon name. I'm not sure exactly why it works, but I made the JSON icon path "icon-name.png" instead of adding .png in the require function call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me that the static assets such as images should be going to /static when webpack builds in dev or prod.

Looking in the config file: [vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/config/index.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/config/index.js), you have the following configuration (provided you haven't changed anything):

```
// Paths
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

So the src should probably be something like:

```
<img src="/static/whatEverMyIconIs.png"/>
```

EDIT:

Looking further into the configs, in [vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.base.conf.js), there's a url-loader plugin which should place images into /static/img:

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

Which could make your src url (depending on how the icons are being loaded):

```
<img src="/static/img/whatEverMyIconIs.png"/>
```