# Vue.js and Laravel - images are not displayed after integrating vuejs with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have a build generated by a vue.js project , and i have integrated that build with laravel.

what i did is as follows :

1 . Put all the Build content in the **Public** folder of laravel except **index.html**

2 . And then, the code of the **index.html** from build folder i copy it and paste it in the  **welcome.blade.php**

And ,now when i run the project from localhost, it runs perfectly except showing any images of the project

The path of the image is this after inspecting the element **static/img/user.jpg**

and i am working on **localhost(xampp)**

so,basically this is my build :

[image]

This is my **Public** folder in laravel **Before**

[image]

And,this is my **Public** folder after putting the **Build** content
[image]

Here,i have merge the files of folder css and js in **Public** folder

And ,the next step was i copy the code from **index.html** from **Build** (the first screenshot) and paste it into the **resources/views/windows.blade.php**

The project runs fine except the images are not displayed,The path of the image is this after inspecting the element **static/img/user.jpg** , Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: What is the url to the images not being shown? Its probably a path setting.

Comment: it shows  static/img/user.jpg

Comment: same issue for me.

Comment: Still looks like a path error. Does your static folder contain a img folder? Or are you planning to use the one on the same level as static folder.

Comment: yes, i already have the img folder in my static folder

Comment: try using {{asset('static/img/user.jpg')}} in the src of the image HTML code.

Comment: please show images with exact location of an image: <img src="{{ asset('static/img/user.jpg') }}">

Comment: i am using build files, i cant do changes to anyone of them

Comment: @shashiverma is static/img/user.jpg an actual image file?

Comment: @Polaris yes, i have a static folder , and inside that  i've three different folder containing different kind of images and one of them is img folder, and the issue is  not only with the img folder , its with all the folders

Comment: @shashiverma The folder and images are being dynamically created? Perhaps you don't have the correct permissions to read the files. Try chmodding the folders recursively to 777.

Comment: I have similar problem; maybe can help you this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working#40493036

Comment: @MahdiIrani see my answer ,may be it can help you.

Comment: More debug needed: In your browser, right click on where the image should be, press "inspect", take screenshot. Also take a screenshot of the js console or the network console so we can see what the actual problem is. Maybe you can also check you Apache log and see if there are actual requests made. Is it 404? We need more info. Also it could be a problem in your Apache config or htaccess since the paths work well in laravel serve. Do all these steps and we will find a solution.

Comment: @ege thanks bro,but my project is running fine, i run my project on php artisan serve.

Comment: @shashiverma ok. Just be aware that when you deploy to production server the problem might occur again.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<html>
<base href="{{url('/')}}">
...
```

or places your base domain there

Answer (score 0):

try `<img class="..." src="img/..." />` and make sure your image folder is in laravel public directory.

Answer (score -1):

what i did,open the terminal from my project file and run the php artisan serve command, and it works fine , loads all the images