# How do you get flickity fullscreen buttons to show up in flickity-fullscreen v1.1.1?

Tags: vuejs2, coffeescript, vue-flickity

I can't get the `fullscreen` button to show as documented [here](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#fullscreen). I have added css and js sources so they are available in the browser:

I can add the `is-fullscreen` class to my parent carousel, getting fullscreen to kick in, but I just can't get the buttons to show up.

My flickity component (in pug) looks like:

```
flickity(class="carousel" ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions" v-if='lotsLoaded')
  .carousel-cell(v-for='lot in lots')
    img(:src='lot.item.primary_image')
```

My flickity options (in coffeescript) are:

```
flickityOptions:
  prevNextButtons: true
  fullscreen: true
```

## **EDIT1**: For my own troubleshooting, I am using the following libraries:

- [vue-flickity](https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity) (`vue-flickity@^1.1.2`), which depends on:

  - `flickity "^2.1.1"` but in my Source Panel (`webpack:///./node_modules/flickity/js/index.js`) the file shows: `Flickity v2.2.0`
- `flickity-fullscreen@^1.1.1` which depends on:

  - `flickity "^2.1.0"`

Comment: What does your CSS look like? The documentation you linked seems to indicate you need to write your own

Comment: @Phil thank you for your discussion. I believe no written CSS is required because of their description  `Enables fullscreen view of carousel. Adds button to view and exit fullscreen.` plus their lack of direction to insert CSS, and the fact that the CSS they provide is the CSS in their `flickity-fullscreen` library they say to include.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification. Their documentation didn't make it clear. Can you see the `<img>` elements in your browser's _Elements_ console? This could be down to difficulties loading dynamic image sources. See [Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)

Comment: You're welcome @Phil. I can see the `img`'s in my Elements Panel, yes.