# Image not showing with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to import an image file from a parent folder in the `public/images` folder to a component (`Categories.vue`), but the image is not showing up.

This is the folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

And this is the code:

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.name" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <div class="img-container">
                  <img v-bind:src="item.src" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                  <p class="text-dark"> {{ item.subtitle }} </p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {   
          name:'first', 
          src:'./public/images/anubis.png', 
          subtitle: 'Anubis' 
        },
        { 
          name:'second', 
          src:'public/images/sarcophagus.png', 
          subtitle: 'Sarcophagus' 
        },
        { 
          name:'third', 
          src:'public/images/ra.png', 
          subtitle: 'Ra' 
        },
        { 
          name:'fourth', 
          src:'public/images/eye-of-ra.png', 
          subtitle: 'Eyes of Ra' 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am pretty sure that I did everything right. I tried using `require()`, but also failed. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You can easly find solution to this on stackoverflow, just spend 5 min looking for it....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728285/how-to-make-vue-display-an-image-from-a-local-path-from-json-file/54731730#54731730

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI?

Comment: @onuriltan yup im using the vue cli

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace your variable

> src:'./public/images/anubis.png'

with

> src:'/images/anubis.png',

This would automatically link to your public folder in all instances.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve static assets from `src/assets` folder so that webpack can see the images, so you need to **put images folder inside src/assets** after that you can do like;

```js
<template>
 <div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key='index'>
   <img :src='require(`@/assets/${image.src}`)' />
   <p class="text-dark"> {{ image.subtitle }} </p>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        { 
          name:'second', 
          src:'images/sarcophagus.png', 
          subtitle: 'Sarcophagus' 
        },
        { 
          name:'third', 
          src:'images/ra.png', 
          subtitle: 'Ra' 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `src` URLs are incorrectly prefixed with `public/`. For URLs based in the `public` directory, the prefix should actually be the [public path](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath), found in `process.env.BASE_URL` (equals `/` by default):

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: `${process.env.BASE_URL}images/anubis.png`,
        },
        {
          src: `${process.env.BASE_URL}images/sarcophagus.png`,
        },
        {
          src: `${process.env.BASE_URL}images/ra.png`,
        },
        {
          src: `${process.env.BASE_URL}images/eye-of-ra.png`,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/referencing-static-assets-under-public-r9u1z?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Note the [`public` directory](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) is provided as a [last resort](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#when-to-use-the-public-folder). The Vue docs recommend putting assets under `src/assets` for optimal builds (i.e., only referenced images would be minified and included in the build). Assuming you used `src/assets/images` to contain your images, the `src` URLs would be:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: require('@/assets/images/anubis.png'),
        },
        {
          src: require('@/assets/images/sarcophagus.png'),
        },
        {
          src: require('@/assets/images/ra.png'),
        },
        {
          src: require('@/assets/images/eye-of-ra.png'),
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/referencing-static-assets-under-public-s8sch?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)