# Images not showing in vuetify pages

Tags: json, vue.js, vuetify.js

The problem is that images are not showing in my webpage. I am reading the image paths from json file.

I already tried removing keep-alive from router-view. But that way the components are destroyed.

App.vue

```
<keep-alive>
    <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

This is a part of the json file:
    {
            "id": 2,
            "hasquestionText": true,
            "text": "This is a Figurative type question",
            "hasquestionImage": true,
            "imagepath": "s3.amazons.com/3/A/queimage.png",
            "hasoptionText": true,
            "optionA": null,
            "optionB": null,
            "optionC": null,
            "optionD": null,
            "optionText": "This is option text",
            "correctoption": "B",
            "hasoptionImage": true,
            "optionimagepath": "s3.amazons.com/3/A/optionimage.png",
            "hasexplanationText": true,
            "explanationtext": "This is Figurative Explanation Text",
            "hasexplanationImage": true,
            "explanationimagepath": "s3.amazons.com/3/A/explanationimage.png",
            "chapterId": 1,
            "subchapterId": 1,
            "questiontypeId": 2,
            "questionlevelId": 2
        },

This is how I am displaying images:

```
<v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center v-show="hqi">
  <v-layout row wrap>
       <v-flex xs12>

         <img :src="'http://' + url1" />

       </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
 </v-container>
```

and script is

```
data () {
    return {
        i: 0
    }   


created: function () {
   this.hqi = this.userData[this.i].hasquestionImage
   this.url1 = this.userData[this.i].imagepath
}
```

The expected result is to show the images in my webpage. But actual result is I am getting

```
<img data-v-29b06b20="" src="http://null">
```

in chrome developer tools. And I am getting this error:

net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Are you sure it's specific to vuetify? It seems like the problem is related to `img` tag and path you provided.

Comment: I think you need to check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Comment: I don't understand why the path is showing null. In json the path is "s3.amazons.com/3/A/queimage.png"

Comment: Hey, as mentioned it probably is a problem with your json path. I've created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dawpqe93/ and there is no problem.