# Image is not rendered with value in settings filke

Tags: vuejs2

In @vue/cli 4.0.5 app I 
set some app settings in app.settings.js file, including task image:

```
export const settingsTaskImg = '/images/task.jpg'
```

which would be used in many parts on the app.

But the problem is that when I try to use this setting value in my component it fails, like :

```
<template>

    <div class="page_content_container item_container">
        taskImg:{{ taskImg }}
        <img alt="Vue logo" src="../../assets/images/task.jpg">
/* the image above is rendered ok */


/* the image above is NOT rendered */
        <img class="pull-left m-3 single_hostel_image_left_aligned" :src="'../../assets'+taskImg" alt="Task Image"/>
```

in the console of my browser I see : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbfzc.jpg
image with path using settings value is not rendered.

Which is valid way ?

**Updated # 2 :** 
In my prinrscreen I see  that valid image has path like

```
/img/task.0e7d942e.jpg
```

I do not have any /img/ in my app, it looks like some temporary dir and image I try to bind is not rendered in this subdirectory...
Have I to call some vuejs method to render it to this path ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)

Comment: Interesting link. But how require.context works here? I do not see how it can be implemented in my case. I mean an unswer which is decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue any attribute if wanted to be changed programatically or dynamically as they call, can be binded with `v-bind`. Such binding will enable to use defined data variables, just like your `taskImg`.

Here's an example on VueMastery https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/attribute-binding/ on how image `src` is being binded.
Hope that explains and you'll be able to make it work from here.

Comment: That does not look like issue. 
In the provided link I see 
Syntax is v-bind: or : for short.
Please, look at Updated # 2:

Comment: Sorry, I could not see those double dots somehow.. 
Yes, the shorthand syntax should be enough. So the issue might be in how you construct the path `'../../assets'+taskImg`, you should bind those together to enclose with double qoutes as src requires.. So it is best the taskImg comes as var, like that:
"`../assets/${taskImg}`"

Comment: Oh, just found a similar question. So will mark as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Comment: How do you think which of proposed answers is valid ?

Comment: Sorry, I though my comment explains. Use back-tickts for string interpolation and those will let you use double quotes within just like my comment above:
 \`"../assets/${taskImg}"\`

Comment: I try to follow it and failed. 1) Is valid path for image /vtasks/src/assets/images/task.jpg? Under /src/ directory?
2) Are there some online fiddle with valid vue/cli 4 project I could modify to make my project?

Comment: If to put image under /public/ directory, the code in link works ok
Looks like  /public/ is proper place for all images? Not “/src/” ?
What confused me in example that it use “/assets/” directory for image?
But that must be “public/assets/” ?