# img tag correctly displays image but v-bind does not

Tags: html, css, image, vue.js

```
            <div class="row">
                <div :key="map.name" v-for="map in match.maps" class="col-lg-4 mt-5">
                    <img width="100" height="50" src="../assets/ovp.png">
                    <img v-bind:src="'../assets/' + map.name + '.png'">
                    {{ map.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
```

The image tag in the example above does show the image, however the v-bind directive does not. What is incorrect? When inspecting the code it looks like this:

```
<div data-v-780f357b="" class="col-lg-4 mt-5">
  <img data-v-780f357b="" src="/img/ovp.3ffb145b.png" width="100" height="50">
  <img data-v-780f357b="" src="../assets/ovp.png">
  ovp
</div>
```

[This is how the website looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKfPg.png)

Comment: This might already be answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working! :)

```
v-bind:style="{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('@/assets/' + map.name + '.png') + ')'}"
```