# Vue.js dynamic reload src of Image

Tags: vue.js, refresh

I have an image changes in the server but without changing the name so I want to reload the source in vuejs without refreshing the page,
This my vue :

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://localhost:8082/files/file.jpeg">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: This might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Comment: thanks but doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `src` the image will reload. you can keep the source as is but add a cache key to the src.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <img 
          :src=`${imageURL}?cache=${cacheKey}`>
    </div>
</template>
```

and in your script add the following:

```
data() {
 return {
      cacheKey: 1,
      imageURL: 'http://localhost:8082/files/file.jpeg'  
 }
}
```

```
updateImgMethod(){
 const nowTime = +new Date()
 this.cacheKey = nowTime
}
```