# How to perform concatenation in <img> tag in the context of VueJS

Tags: image, vue.js, concatenation

I am trying to perform concatenation in img tag and here below is what i am trying to do:

```
<div class="vx-row"> 
  <div v-for="item in items" class="vx-col" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <div class="w-full mb-base">
      <vx-card>
        ...
        <img :src="require('./img/stars_' + item.id + '_logo.png')" alt=""/>
        ... 
      </vx-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to concatenate the item.id to the image path as i am making my code dynamic such that when the cards are displayed then the respective image is displayed.

Please let me know how it can be done, initially i could see images in respective cards but then i tried using

```
<img :src="require(`./img/stars_${this.$route.params.item_id}_logo.png`)">
```

in other components then i get error every where.

Here is the error that i get everywhere:

[image]

Comment: try this...

<img :src="require(`./img/stars_${$route.params.item_id}_logo.png`)">

Comment: Okay sure that can be done in other components, but what about the one i have showed in the code ?

Comment: Did you check if your route.params has the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can try a shorthand that webpack will use.

HTML:

```
    <img :src="getByPath(item.id)" v-bind:alt="item.id">
```

Method:

```
getByPath(id) {
    return require('./img/stars_' + id + '_logo.png')
}
```

Comment: Not working, image is broken in every cards, is there any other way

Comment: Are u sure that the path is correct ? The current oath says that go and search the image from the current position and then go inside img

Comment: yes, the path is correct, if i just hard code it by replacing the item.id then the image is displayed. But rather i want to make it dynamic

Comment: try with double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: Nope it does not work as i have used the shorthand.

Comment: well strange..leaving this stackoverflow answers here that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working now! I found an answer in the link you sent me.

Comment: Nice! If you want send me the solution here to update my post and if you want to just take back the down vote :)

Comment: Sure i was about to tell you, shall i send you the answer, or shall i edit your answer ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47480286/14882601 this is the answer that helped me. You update your answer here.

Comment: If you can edit it go for it otherwise send here the answer and I will update it

Answer (score 1):

you can do with method like below code
try this:

```
<div class="vx-row"> 
  <div v-for="item in items" class="vx-col" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <div class="w-full mb-base">
      <vx-card>
        ...
        <img :src="getImgUrl(item.id)" alt=""/>
        ... 
      </vx-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and create method:

```
getImgUrl(value) {
     return `./img/stars_${value}_logo.png`
},
```