# Image dynamically not printing in Vue that are received over local JSON

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am passing JSON that is in one of folders over router-view in App.vue.
The component is receiving that JSON over props, I can no problem display data that I receive.
But when I want to bind it to image :src , image is not printing.
In console.log there is no error.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in userRepo" :key="index">
      <img :src="item.imageLink" alt="">
      {{item.imageLink}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:['person'],
  data(){
    return {
      userRepo: this.person[0].githubRepository
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I open elements, there is normal insert

Comment: So what is the value of a `item.imageLink`, is it valid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)

Comment: @AJT82 yes, it is valid. You just get string '../assets/img/test.png', but somehow is not working.

Comment: Ah, did you check the link provided by Oscar, that will probably solve your issue :)

Comment: @AJT82 Yes, not working still.. :( I will call JSON locally and filter it. Maybe that way it will be fine.