# How to bind an image src attribute to a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2

I'm a beginner in vue.js . I've create a Vue component "cards" that has some Vue componet "card" . I have an error in **:src="{ card.imgSource }"** . I don't know what should I do to solve it . Please help me .

```
Vue.component('cards' , {
    props: ['cards'],
    template : `
    <div class="row products">
            <card v-for="(card , index) in cards" :card="card" :index="index"></card>
    </div>
    `
  });


  Vue.component('card' , {
    props :['card' , 'index'],
    template : `
        <div class="col-md-4 product">
        <div class="card">
            <img :src="{ card.imgSource }" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ card.title }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ card.body }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        </div>
    `
  });


  let imgs = "img/shoe_img.jpg";

  let app = new Vue({
    el : '#app',
    data : {
      cards : [
        { title : 'Product 1' , body : "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content." ,imgSource : imgs },
        { title : 'Product 2' , body : "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content." ,imgSource: imgs},
        { title : 'Product 3' , body : "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content." ,imgSource: imgs}
      ],
      alert : {
        title : '',
        message : '',
        show : false ,
        type : ''
      }
    },

  });
```

Comment: remove the brackets `:src="card.imgSource"`, also data should be a factory, ie its a function that returns an object

Comment: I think it's duplicate question, and you can find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it for `:src="card.imageSource"`.

With the `:src="{ card.imageSource }"` you basically try to pass an object literal with a malformed object property.

Assuming your `imageSource` is `'http://example.com/img.jpg'` you are effectively passing as a `src` the object `{ 'http://example.com/img.jpg' }` which is not a valid object *(nor a valid image URL)*.

To understand what I mean when I say you are passing an object literal, try doing that: `:src="{ key: card.imageSource }"` and inspect the DOM. Your error will disappear, and you will most likely see `src="[object Object]"`.

If it's still a bit hard to understand, try reading the section on [interpolations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Interpolations) in the Vue.js documentation, it will help you.