# VueJS3 dynamic asset

Tags: vue.js, assets, vuejs3

I load some images like this in my template:

```
<img
    v-if="idRobot === 7"
    src="~@/assets/img/faceTibot.png" />
```

But I'd like to load the asset dynamically. For example, something like this would be great:

```
<img
    v-if="idRobot === 7"
    :src="`~@/assets/img/${dynamicasset}.png`" />
```

Actually, when I do this, VueJS thinks I want to load the string `"~@/assets/img/${dynamicasset}.png"`.

Is what I want even possible in VueJS3?
Ah, BTW I searched SO and found this but suggested `require` solutions don't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47480286/1098303

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution ?

```html
<img :src="require(`~@/assets/img/${dynamicasset}.png`)" />
```