# Load images dynamically with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuetify.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm running a webpack web app on AWS S3 and I have to dynamically show images. I found this following code thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working):

```
getImgUrl(nameImage) {
    let images = require.context("../static/images/members/", false, /\.jpg$/);
    return images("./" + nameImage + ".jpg");
}
```

And in my vuetify template:

```
<template v-else-if="activeTab == 0">
    <img
       :src="getImgUrl(chunk[i-1])"
    />
</template>
```

The problem is the images are not loaded as my aws server returns a 403 Forbidden error strict origin when cross origin.

That's weird because I don't have any problem with another image that I load in my topbar with this code:

```
<v-img
    :alt="appName"
    class="shrink mr-2"
    contain
   :src="require('../static/images/logo.jpg').default"
   width="40"
   height="40" 
/>
```

Do you have any other idea how I could require my images dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just had to add .default to the value to return:

```
getImgUrl(nameImage) {
    let images = require.context("../static/images/members/", false, /\.jpg$/);
    return images("./" + nameImage + ".jpg").default;
}
```

Remember kids: if require() doesn't work, just add .default at the end #SuperSmart

To be true I didn't understand why I had to do this, but if you know feel free to tell me in the comments