# How to load static file image in Vue component with Django Application

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I am currently using laravel-mix, Django, and Vue together. I would like to load the static image inside the Vue component. My images store in `static/img` folder

First of all, I have set up an alias in Webpack config pointing to the static folder.

const path = require('path')

```
let publicPath = 'src/static'
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.join(__dirname, publicPath)
        },
    },
}
```

And load the image in Vue component

```
<img :src='require(`@/img/Blue.jpg`).default' alt="">
```

I can't load images and Webpack generated new images into the images folder. How to prevent it and load image correct

Answer (score 0):

change this from

```
<img :src='require(`@/img/Blue.jpg`).default' alt="">
```

To:

```
<img :src="require('@/img/Blue.jpg')" alt="">
```

hope this may be help u

Comment: it can't it will generate to like that `<img data-v-5be83aa6="" src="[object Module]" alt="">`. and it will generate new image to the images folder

Comment: what exactly u want

Comment: I want to display the image and disable generate image when webpack complied

Comment: refer it:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working in my case