# How to use dynamic images in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to display images from an assets folder in a Nuxt but it won't work even if the `src` value in the HTML is correct.

Here is an excerpt of the code.

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <div class="item-img">
   <img :src="`../assets/imgs/${item.img}`"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above path is correct as the component is inside a pages folder at the same root level as the assets folder.

I have image filenames in an array like so:

```js
data() {
  return {
    images: ['image0.jpg', 'image1.jpg'],
  ...
}
```

There is an async function that is making an API call
to fetch some items. When the API is finished a random image is added to each item.

```js
async getMovies() {
  const data = axios.get `api_call_here`)
  const result = await data
  result.data.results.forEach((item) => {
    let randomImg = 
    this.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    this.images.length)]
    item.img = randomImg
    this.items.push(item)
  })
},
```

I am sure the path to the images is correct and that they exist in the specified folder. I also know the path works because I can display any single image from the same assets folder inside another component at the same level.

I think I have tried every combination for the interpolation inside the `src` attribute and nothing has worked.

Lastly, I can see the correct path in the elements themselves when I inspect them in the developer console. What is even more baffling is the images seem to be taking up the appropriate space on the page but they are empty (blank space).

I have run out of ideas. If anyone can help me figure out what is going wrong I'd be very grateful.

Comment: have you defined `items` in *data* ?

Comment: @Saeed yes, `items` is defined on data also. I forgot to mention that the other values of each item in the `v-for` display perfectly fine, so there is no problem there. It is simply that the `img` element is not displaying the images despite the fact that the correct paths are in the HTML.

Comment: `taking up the appropriate space`, did you check width and height of images? any *overflow hidden* style or something like that?

Comment: @Saeed there is an overflow hidden on the div wrapping the img tag. The height and width on the img tag itself are 100%. I just tried pasting in a url using the dev console and it immediately showed on the page, so I think the CSS is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)

Comment: Yep, you're probably looking at the wrong place here. As @Kapcash proposed, a `require` should do the trick when it comes down to dynamic stuff. Here is the part in [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets#images) related to Nuxt images.

Comment: due to the nature of the beast, rather than needing to rebuild your app every time you add a new item, look into storing non-design related files and images on the server's filesystem or s3 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Vue3/Nuxt3

https://www.lichter.io/articles/nuxt3-vue3-dynamic-images/

---

### For Nuxt2

Try to use it this way

```html
<img :src="require(`../assets/imgs/${item.img}`)" />
```

As shown in the [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets/#images) regarding the images.

Comment: Please note that this solution does not work in Nuxt 3, it will only work in Nuxt 2

Comment: @Maurice rectification, this only works with Webpack, not with Vite. Nuxt3 can be used with Webpack5.

Comment: good callout. I guess by default, the Nuxt3 project generator configures new projects with Vite, which is why this option didn't work for me.

Also worth noting is that there is an issue open on GH around better handling for this situation: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/7121

Comment: I have tried this but not working on nuxt 3 version

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya it was stated that it was only for Vue2/Nuxt2 indeed. Updated my answer with a solution for Vue3/Nuxt3.

Comment: This does not work in nuxt 3, can't find the require() modules. To with dynamic image in your template you need the static URL and nuxt 3 does not serve files in the assets/ directory at a static URL like /assets/my-file.png. If you need a static URL, use the public/ directory.

Comment: @OlaboyeDavidTobi please read the answer again, there is a `Vue3/Nuxt3` section.

Comment: Don't know about Vue3 but see https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets for Nuxt3

Comment: @OlaboyeDavidTobi nothing that is not already in my answer above. Using `public` has quite some drawbacks tho (as written above).

Answer (score 6):

in Nuxt v3, you can use it like so

```html
<script setup>
import img1 from `~/path/to/img1`
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="img1" />
</template>
```

Comment: How can you get this to work with dynamic images in Nuxt 3?

Comment: Just import all images that you may need dynamically. you may place them in an object or array.
If you have a ton of images and is not doable for you, most probably must move your images on a CDN and get full URLs from there.
Another option would be to place your images in the `public/` folder.
I would also like to know if there's a better way to dynamically import assets in Nuxt 3. Will come up with an update if I find out.

Comment: I have the same issue on asset and used a public folder for now but it is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt 3 Vue composition API You can put images in public directory or assets directory.

If You will use images from public directory it will work but webpack will dont optymize them so it's not a professional solution.

If u want use images from assets directory dynamically, first You need to get a new "webpack" path with new changed filename. You can do it in code by import image like this:

```
import img_1 from '~/assets/fences_1.png';
import img_2 from '~/assets/fences_1.png';
```

Then You can optionally have an object which can use this data for looping.

```
{
      name: "name",
      photo_url: img_1,
      link_url: "/index",
    },
```

as a path use imported img_1 it will change automatically.

Now You can use it in html like this:

```
:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + item.photo_url + ')' }"
```

It works in development and production.

Answer (score 0):

Worinkg with Nuxt 3 and `import img1 from ~/path/to/img1` works fine but I've had an error while working with typescript. I think in Nuxt 2 dynamic `:src` attributes was working better :).

Anyway if you like to play with typescript and don't want to have an errors see my approach below. `$slugify` is just an extra plugin I needed to convert attribute to right image name.

**Stack**:

- Nuxt 3 with typescript ([docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets))
- Tailwind

---

**plugins/slugify.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      slugify: (text: string) => {       
        return `${
          text
            .toLocaleLowerCase()
            .trim()
            .replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '')
            .replace(/[\s_-]+/g, '-')
            .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '')
          }`
      }
    }
  }
})
// "Any String" will be converted to "any-string"
```

**components/ImageComponent.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps({
    imageSrc: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
})
</script>

<template>
  <div
    :class="`bg-[url('${props.imageSrc)}')]`"
  >
  <div>
</template>
```

**Usage**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>My awesome image.png</h1>
    <ImageComponent
      class="w-16 h-16 bg-contain"
     :image-src="`${$slugify('My awesome image.png')}`"
    />
  </div>
</template?
```

my-awesome-image.png must be placed in `public` folder

---

### Another way - the easiest one!!!

You can also use [Nuxt Image](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/) where you can pass image :src in a dynamic way :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i just found an easy solution for Nuxt 3. I used `<NuxtImg>` for dynamic images. It worked both during development and in my production build.

Note that `<NuxtImg>` by default looks up files in public directory, in my case directory looked like this `public` > `images`

```html
<NuxtImg :src="'images/' + yourImage" />
```