# can't access props string in image source in Vue (with Laravel 9)

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9, inertiajs, vue-props

I'm trying to show an image in Vue where the source is pulled from props (from Laravel). The props are there, but I can't get it to render in the browser. In fact, if I try to display any value on its own it shows up blank, which I assume is the problem.

Dashboard.vue

```
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue';
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";

const props = defineProps({
    games: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({}),
    },
});

</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Dashboard" />

    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Play a Game
            </h2>
        </template>
        {{ $page.props.games.image }}
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

If I remove '.image' and just use '$page.props.games', I get the full object.

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Memory", "image": "html://imagePath", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ]
```

Do I need to provide a more detailed model for the object and specify the types? Or is the problem somehow on the back end?

web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\Game;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        Log::debug(Game::all());
        return Inertia::render(
            'Dashboard',
            [
                'games' => Game::all()
            ]
            );
    }
}
```

Game.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'image',
    ];
}
```

My vue devtools don't show props.games either (I've read there's a problem with vue 3) or any other variables that I pass down and can use, so it's no help in determining what's happening.

As always, any help or suggestions on where to look next are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting not an object but an array

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Memory", "image": "html://imagePath", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null } ]
```

Game::all() return a collection. so you need to loop over games and get the image

```
 <template v-for="game in $page.props.games">
    {{ game.image }}
 </template>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was part of the solution - and I should have realised that I had more than one entry in games.

The other part that I found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working is that I needed to use ':src' instead of 'src', which I still need to understand.

Comment: :src means you're binding a variable as the source.