# cannot show my pictures stored in folder using v-for vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new to Vuejs. I have two pictures store in my website. the v-for allocated the information correctly inside `databaseListItem`. The path is
`/opt/lampp/htdocs/products_db/stored_images/cms.png`

[image]

The html comes with vue2, and I want to use the v-for with {{}} to show each pictures, This is html code.

```
     <tr v-for="show_all_item in databaseListItem">
        <!--first attempt, required not declared-->
        <!-- <img :src="require(`@/htdocs/products_db/stored_images/${show_all_item.itemimage}`)" />     -->

        <!--second attempt, itemimage not decalred-->
        <!-- <img :src="`/products_db/stored_images/${show_all_item.itemimage}`"> -->
        <!--wrong--> 
        <img :src="{{show_all_item.itemimage}}" />

 
        <td scope="row">[Name]</td>
        <td scope="row">[Code]</td>
        <td scope="row">[Spec]</td>
        <td scope="row">[Spec]</td>
    </tr>
```

databaseListItem is sorted in myjs with vue. So it already has the named in inputt_item.itemimage  (cms.png) correctly.

```
new Vue({
el: "#app",
data() {
  return {
    databaseListItem: [],
    inputt_item: {itemname: "", itemcode: "", itemdescription: "", itemvariant: "", 

      itemimage: "", itemts: ""}, //itemimage stored the name of the image ex. cms.png

    selected: {}
  };
},
```

Both of the attempt are not correct, how can I only using v-for and show the correct path for the image I stored? I try to use img tag and v-img, but still nothing shown? Any problem with my code? Any help would appreciate.

Comment: Try `:src="show_all_item.itemimage"` rather.

Comment: Also, if you're using Webpack and want to load dynamic images: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57567343/8816585

Comment: kissu, thanks but I tried it said itemimage not declared, I suppose declared on js : (

Comment: If you have some difficulties with having it properly displayed when the path is dynamic, focus on having a hardcoded image first. `/opt` is probably not the good path to have here, you should be referencing something in your Vue project.

Comment: `/opt` is clearly "above" your Vue project, so you'll need to copy your assets there because Webpack has no idea what those files are (even if on your system). Mind sharing the structure of your project?

Comment: yes kissu you are right, the path is "too detail" and it makes does not return the image I want, now `<td scope="row"> <img src="stored_images/cms.png" alt="show_all_item.itemimage"> </td>` is the most correct if I only need same picture shown again and again.

Comment: Does it work with `stored_images/cms.png`?

Comment: yes, `stored_images/cms.png` works. but when I try `src="stored_images/{{show_all_item.itemimage}}` and it has error again : (

Comment: ```:src="`stored_images/${show_all_item.itemimage}` ``` it should be, `{{ }}` syntax is only for actual text.

Comment: omg it works, come to london and  I owe you a drink! kissu

Comment: Haha, might happen sooner than you expect. Is your issue solved buddy?

Comment: really really solved, thanks kissu, let's conencted sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to

```html
<img :src="require(`stored_images/${show_all_item.itemimage}`)" />
```

As shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57567343/8816585

Also, keep in mind that the mustache syntax (aka `{{ }}`) is only for actual text, not for HTML attributes.

---

PS: assuming that you properly do have `cms.png` in `itemimage`.