# How I can set dynamic background image in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend

I want to make my navbar dynamic. I want to change it's background image.

I try this:

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg"v-bind:style="headerStyle">
this.headerStyle = {
                    backgroundImage: 'url("../../assets/img/sky-views/3.png") !important'
                }
```

When I do that and inspect it I see this:

[image: inspect result]

And there is no image, it cant find the image.

But when I add a class to element and give same path to class it show the image.

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" class="header-wrapper">
...
    <style lang="scss">
    .header-wrapper {
            background-image: url("../../assets/img/sky-views/3.png") !important;
        }
    </style>
```

When I inspect I see:

[image: inspect result 2]

What is the point I miss? Why the result path is different? How can I make it properly?

Answer (score 2):

When Webpack compiles your Vue application, it knows to convert CSS `url()` paths to their compiled counterparts. However, `this.headerStyle` is just an arbitrary object variable in a Vue component script: Webpack doesn't have the context to transform that URL.

In an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47480286/2977638), the `require()` function is recommended for asking Webpack to transform the URL. For your script in particular, the new variable would look something like:

```js
this.headerStyle = {
  backgroundImage: `url("${require('../../assets/img/sky-views/3.png')}") !important`
}
```

And you would `v-bind:style="headerStyle"` the exact same way in the template.

Note that the output will be dependent on how your build is configured. In my testing, I got a huge base64-encoded string by default in the outputted style attribute (rather than a URL to an asset). However, the end visual result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I found is give dynamic class name.

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg"v-bind:class="headerClass">
...
this.headerClass= 'night'
...
.night {
            background-image: url("../../assets/img/sky-views/nightImage.png") !important;
        }
</style>
```