# Dynamically import images from prop - Vue3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

How can I import images dynamically only sending their name as a prop from parent to child?

Parent:

```
<Message
   v-if="cartItems.length == 0"
   text="Još nemate proizvoda u košarici."
   imageName="empty-cart"
/>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <img
      :src="`../assets/${props.imageName}.png`"
      :alt="`${props.imageName}-img`"
    />
    <p>{{ props.text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  text: String,
  imageName: String,
});
</script>
```

I get error: `GET http://localhost:5173/assets/empty-cart.png 404 (Not Found)`

But when I change it to static image import it works:

```
<template>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <img
      src="../assets/empty-cart.png"
      alt="img"
    />
    <p>{{ props.text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What does the (not working) URL look like in the inspector at runtime?

Comment: For dynamic image loading you can look out this one 
Link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working-with-webpack

Answer (score 3):

Using Vite, the solution is to use [new URL(url, import.meta.url)](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url)

For example,

```js
<template>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <img :src="imageUrl" :alt="`${imageName}-img`" />
    <p>{{ props.text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  text: String,
  imageName: String
})

const imageUrl = computed(
  () => new URL(`/src/assets/${props.imageName}.png`, import.meta.url).href
)
</script>
```

As a side note the `props` in `props.imageName` is unnecessary when used in `<template>` code. It is automatically stripped so it's not important to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `require()` for that.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <img
      :src="require(`@/assets/${props.imageName}`)"
      alt="img"
    />
    <p>{{ props.text }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this example `props.imageName` should be the image name with its extensions. For example like, `props.imageName = "empty-cart.png"`