# Dynamic requiring React Native images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on including some flags to represent countries in my react native project. I discovered that you can't dynamically require images like the example below in react native.

```
require(`../assets/flags/32/${countryCode}.png`)
```

So given the SO response I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names) I was thinking of creating a function with a switch statement that would return the required image back when passed the correct flag code.  Something like the below.

```
export const Flags = (countryCode) => {
 switch (countryCode) {
   case 'US':
    return require('../assets/flags/32/US.png');
   ....
 }
};
```

I'll have well over 200 cases given this solution.  Is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of how cumbersome it would be to manually require all the images, can you add [them to your App image assets](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources) and require them via `uri`?

```
<Image source={{uri: 'flags/32/'+countryCode}} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
```

Other than that I think your proposal is the only other solution.. you could clean it up slightly by making it a JS module.

**Flags.js**

```
exports.US = require('../assets/flags/32/US.png')
exports.UK = require('../assets/flags/32/UK.png')
exports.FR = require('../assets/flags/32/FR.png')
exports.JP = require('../assets/flags/32/JP.png')
...
```

Then just reference it like so.

**Component.js**

```
import Flags from './Flags'

<Image source={Flags[countryCode]} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
```

Comment: Thanks brad this helped.