# Set image name from obj to source React Native

Tags: image, react-native

I've a ploblem with image Source and Obj's parameter.
Inside the local object I have `IMG_NAME: 'A.png'` like so:
[image]
I would like concatenate this value with source like
[image]
but I know require doesn't support concatenate so I decided ask you this question about the best way to solve this problem.

How can I try to solve this problem ([**my solve screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZQFu.png)), and error image ([**Error reponse**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrRCC.png))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic requiring React Native images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689099/dynamic-requiring-react-native-images)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there are 4 simple way to use a dynamic source in the Image Component:

1) You can use images that are already bundled into the app:

> Images From Hybrid App's Resources 
>  If you are building a hybrid
>   app (some UIs in React Native, some UIs in platform code) you can
>   still use images that are already bundled into the app.
>
> For images included via Xcode asset catalogs or in the Android
>   drawable folder, use the image name without the extension:
>
> <  `Image source={{uri: 'app_icon'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />`
>
> For images in the Android assets folder, use the asset:/ scheme:
>
> < `Image source={{uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png'}} style={{width: 40,
>   height: 40}} />`
>
> These approaches provide no safety checks. It's up to you to guarantee
>   that those images are available in the application. Also you have to
>   specify image dimensions manually.

https ://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-app-s-resources

2) You can use require('imagePath') into the object.

```
{
  "id_letter": "1",
  "name_letter":"A",
  "img_name":require('./app/assets/images/imgname.jpg');
}
```

3) You can storage the images in the web and you can use:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http: //site.com/app/assets/images/'+data.img_name}}/>
```

4) You can storage the images using the library https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob.

Comment: Ops, I'm sorry. I will edit the answer to be clearer. Excuse me for that.

Comment: Yeah i already thought about storage the images in the web server, but originally I wanted store them on local folder of app. About second option I wanna say that I use JSON object and inside it I can't keep value like: require('./app/assets/images/A.png')

Comment: So, the way i figure it, certainly, send the images to a web server is the best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I know, but I create offline app and would like so that images loaded locally

Comment: Ok, I'll still continue to help. I'll make some tests here. I hope we'll figure out a solution. I will feedback.

Comment: @Metallistener What do you think about use the library react-native-fetch-blob: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob? You can storage the images in the local storage and you can recover using a dynamic source.

Comment: Yes I think I'll use it, but I was hoping solve it without third-party things)

Comment: can you look at image?I added it in general question.Why is this happening?

Comment: Yes, I can. I think this error is due to you are trying to use a concatene string in the require function. But, unfortunately, the require function only receive a literal string. What do you think about you dive into the reac-native-fetch-blob code? I hope that the best way path to build what you are doing is using a AsyncStorage to storage the image in the local device and, so, you will can use a Image source={{uri:...}}.

Comment: Please, give just a minute. I am testing here.

Comment: I was testing require( `path/${data.img_name}` ), but unfortunately, doesn't works.

Comment: Yeah I know that It doesn't work)then I think the best way to solve this ploblem is use AsyncStorage How you tell me

Comment: You're welcome! I Will continue to try,  If I figure out a best solution, I will post here

Comment: I'll be glad if you share with solution

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the local object change to this

```
{
   "id_letter": "1",
   "name_letter": "A",
   "image" require("./app/assets/images/A.png")
}
```

and then Component change to

```
<Image style={styles.letter_image} source={data.image} />
```

**Edit Another Method use switch case statement**

require not support dynamic path. Use switch case statement to solve this

```
function getImage(img_name) {
  switch(img_name) {
    case "A.png": return require("./app/assets/images/A.png");
    case "B.png": return require("./app/assets/images/B.png");
  }
}

<Image style={styles.letter_image} source={getImage(data.img_name)} />
```

Comment: I use JSON object, there is not use require how I know

Comment: **require** not support dynamic path
I think you should to use switch case statement instead

switch (img_name) {
   "A.png": return require("./app/assets/images/A.png");
   "B.png": return require("./app/assets/images/B.png");
}

Comment: still not dynamic