# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this warning in my project: "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`". I'm loading an image from sampleProducts.json to Recommendend.js and pass it as props in Products.js, but the image won't load because of the warning.

sampleProducts.json

```
"recommended": {
    "product1": {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "require('../images/sample1.png')",
        "name": "Sample Product",
    },
```

Recommmended.js

```
{Object.values(recommended).map(product => (
                    <Products
                        key={ product.id }
                        productImage={ product.image }
                        productName={ product.name }
                    />
                ))}
```

Products.js

```
<Card style={ styles.card }>
                    <CardItem>
                        <Image style={ styles.productImage } source={ productImage} resizeMode='contain' />
                    </CardItem>
                    <CardItem>
                        <Body>
                            <Text style={ styles.productName }>{productName}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </CardItem>
                </Card>
```

Comment: Please post the warning as its outputted to you.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `require()` on `recommended.product1.image` and make it just "../images/sample1.jpg"

Change your `Image` component's source prop to be 
`` source={require(`${recommended.product1.image}`)} ``

Comment: gives me an error about require expects a string. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **require** in JSON format and **require** not support dynamic path.

Can you use switch case statement instead ?

```
function getImage(img_name) {
  switch(img_name) {
    case "sample1.png": return require("../images/sample1.png");
    case "sample2.png": return require("../images/sample2.png");
  }
}
```

and change JSON to

```
"recommended": {
    "product1": {
        "id": "1",
        "image": "sample1.png",
        "name": "Sample Product",
    }
}
```

and use with component below

```
<Image source={getImage(productImage)} />
```

If you don't want to use switch case check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714421/1754750) for other methods

Comment: I'll try different methods. Thanks for helping