# How would you load (hundreds) of images in a React Native app?

Tags: image, react-native

I have to develop a mobile application that will have hundred of "cards" with an image. All images will be locally stored. I have seen that, in React Native, images are loaded using *require* and a constant file path string as parameter. I can create an array with all images user could need, but I don't know how memory is handled in this situations. Is there a better approach to solve that?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names). You can't load bundled images via an array as the `require` statements are pre-compiled when the bundler runs; each image must be present at the path supplied. In terms of performance, will hundreds of images be on screen at once? This might be an issue on low-end devices, but if not, you should be fine referring to them all via `require`.

Comment: I said array and I meant object. The idea is to load a JSON with a collection of items to display individually in "cards". Each item has an associated image. I see that i cannot load this imatge dynamically, but my idea was to do an initial load inside the images pool object like `images["key"]=require("literal/path/to/image");` I will never show more than one image at the same time. What I was not sure of was whether it was ok in terms of memory usage to "require" some hundreds of images that will probably won't be needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it yet, but [`react-native-fast-image`](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) might be what you are looking for!

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think I made myself clear enough. I do not have to display all images at once. My concern was about requiring hundreds of  locally stored images that will probably not be displayed.

Comment: I know this post is very old but did you have your solution ?