# How to show images dynamically with react native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native

I want to build an album app with react native, the main idea is to use a `sectionList` and show the data in an array like this:

```js
class CustomImage extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
          <Image style={styles.Img} source={this.props.imageName} />
          <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class DisplayAnImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <SectionList
          sections={[
            {titile: 'small soldier', data: ["./gifs/2.gif", "./gifs/3.gif", "./gifs/4.gif"]}

          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <CustomImage name={item} fromWeb={false} imageName={require(item)} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Above code was indented to make it work inspirited by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245762/2288944)

I have already put the gifs folder under the project folder, and if I using a static string as `source={require(url)}` in the `Image` component, things will work, but when the `url` came out of an array items iteration, it will not work.

How can I make this work with react native?

### EDIT

Don't know if I could edit to make it more specificly, the really thing I want to do is to use a generated array like this:

```js
function numberRange(start, end){
  return new Array(end-start).fill().map((d,i) => {
    var url = "./gifs/" + ( i+start) + ".gif";
    return require(url)
  });
}
export default class DisplayAnImage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <SectionList
          sections={[
            {title: 'small soldier', data: numberRange(2,30)},
            {title: 'small soldier', data: numberRange(31,60)}

          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <CustomImage name={item} fromWeb={false} imageName={item} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Don't know if have a way to use this array generator to make an array or I have to enter the path one by one on bare hand :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is a javascript keyword with a **preload** nature.

And, images will not related to path at runtime --- provide a path to it will not get anything. it becomes bundle resources, so with `console.log` you can only see resource token related to bundle ex: `_1` `_2`.

It will not work even change `require("./gifs/1.gif")` to `require("./gifs/"+"1.gif")`.

Try this:

```js
data: [require("./gifs/2.gif"), require("./gifs/3.gif"), require("./gifs/4.gif")]
```

Comment: Hi, Val, thanks, it works, already accept that, and don't know if it is properly to ask, actually the data array was generated by a generator, is there a way to work through that? check the edit, thanks.

Comment: @armnotstrong just modified my answer with *image -> bundle* resources relation. Since *file path* has no meanings at runtime, and after tried many ways with no success, I don't think it's possible...