# How can I use props with image source to create usable component in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I use props with image source to create usable component in react native? How should I change my code?

**CategoryBox :**

```
class CategoryBox extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{width: this.props.width, height: this.props.width/2 - 30,
                borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#dddddd',}}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
                    <Image style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: null}}
                           source={require(this.props.image)}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.BoxViewTextHandle}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 10, color: '#b63838'}}>{this.props.type}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{this.props.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 10}}>{this.props.price}$</Text>
                    <StarRating
                        disabled={true}
                        maxStars={5}
                        rating={this.props.rating}
                        starSize={10}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );

    }

}


export default CategoryBox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require it's not dynamic.

So you should pass `require("someString")` from your `this.props.image` and then :

```
<Image style={{ flex: 1, width: null, height: null}}
   source={this.props.image}
/>
```

More details about [How use require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is.

```
export const Icons = { icon:require("something") }
```

Then create a Image component with any name and it can look like

```
<AppImage source={Icons.icon} styles={your styles}/>
```

You can reuse both the images const and AppImage too.