# React Native - Whats wrong with rendering images from local storage dynamically?

Tags: image, react-native

**I tried almost every solution from stackoverflow & github, But unfortunately nothing is working to me !**

I need to render image according to an click event. My app is fine when i put the hard coded require value like this

```
<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={require('./hulk.png')} />
```

But it doesn't work if i store the value to a variable and then put this variable into the require like this

```
let legendPic = `./${this.props.title.toLowerCase()}.png`;
........
<Image style={{width: 50, height: 50}} source={require(legendPic)} />
```

Here is the my renderDescription method's code

```
renderDescription = () => {
    if(this.props.id === this.props.selectedLibraryId) {
      let legendPic = `./${this.props.title.toLowerCase()}.png`;
      console.log(legendPic);
      return(
        <CardSection>
          <Image 
            style={{height: 50, width: 50}} 
            //source={require(legendPic)} 
          />
          <Animatable.Text animation='lightSpeedIn'>{this.props.description}</Animatable.Text>
        </CardSection>
      );
    }
  }
```

From the console i get the desired output, but it doesn't work with require.

This is my simple app, when i click any title - description will appear. Left empty space is to show image but i can't solve this issue anymore.
[image: Screen Shot of App]

> I tried all the possible solution from here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Console Output:
[image]

> In case you want to see the whole source code [Github Link](https://github.com/robin3317/legends)

**Thank's**

Comment: Are you sure you've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42245762/7581249)?

Comment: @Milore yes, it works when i use path as a string like require('./hulk.png'), but when i use a variable with string literal instead of string it doesn't work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names) That is because `react-native` currently doesn't support using dynamic strings for `require` making this question a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

you should include all required assets into an object like this:

```
const assets = {
  key: require('./path-to-image'),
  key2: require('./path-to-image'),
  key3: require('./path-to-image'),
}
```

where you name your keys based on your props.title

and then you change your image dynamically from that object like this:

```
renderDescription = () => {
    if(this.props.id === this.props.selectedLibraryId) {
      let legendPic = assets[this.props.title.toLowerCase()];
      console.log(legendPic);
      return(
        <CardSection>
          <Image 
            style={{height: 50, width: 50}} 
            source={legendPic} 
          />
          <Animatable.Text animation='lightSpeedIn'>{this.props.description}</Animatable.Text>
        </CardSection>
      );
    }
  }
```