# React native Config - Setting .env

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-config

I am using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) for setting environment variable in my react native project. I have a local image url in my `.env` config file. I am able to get the local image url in my component using `Config.LOGO_URL`. Code snippets of files are following:

Environment config file i.e `.env`

```
LOGO_URL='logo.png'
```

I am using the `LOGO_URL` in the component as below:

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';

render() {
    <View>
        <Image source={require(`../../assets/images/${Config.LOGO_URL}`)} />                                
    </View>
}
```

When I am trying to use config variable `Config.LOGO_URL` in Image `source` I am getting error `invalid call in require()`. However, hardcoded path to image source is working as expected.

Am I missing something? Thanks! in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with Config its with the way that you are accessing the images in runtime, as its a static resource you will have to require it beforehand and the use something like a switch to change your logo.
More info in the below answer on requiring images.
[React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)