# Dynamic Path is not working in require react native

Tags: image, react-native

Below is the code

```
  require("index/components/" + name); //fails
  require("index/components/myComponent"); //work fine
```

any good solution ?

Comment: what is name?...

Comment: where are you assigning value to name variable and which values? can you add whole code?

Comment: ` const path = `../../../assets/Static_Icons/${name}.${fileType}`;`
  `  iconSrc = require(path);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic paths in require are not currently supported.
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30868078/9994657) answer

> This is covered in the documentation under the section "Static Resources":
>
> The only allowed way to refer to an image in the bundle is to literally write require('name-of-the-asset') in the source.

You can use a `switch` statement to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about it but you can try to write it in ES6

`` require(`index/components/${name}`); ``