# Image : Dynamic path for local images

Tags: image, react-native, expo

Beginner with React Native here.

I'm working on a small App which needs to display an image according to a random number. For exemple if I got 203, I want to display the image Project/img/203.png (random number is between 1 and 726)

The first thing I tried was require(dynamicPath), after reading documentation I understood that was not a good way to do it and I don't want to require each 726 image staticly.
Then I tried with the uri syntax :

```js
//Executed from Project/components/ folder
loadImage(number){
  imgUri = '../img/'+number.toString()+'.png'  
  return(
    <Image source={{uri: imgUri}} />
)
```

The application does launch but there is no image displayed (even with height/width style set).
Examples I had seen with uri syntax were about images recieved from a web URL so I'm not sure it allows to get it from a local storage, but i can not find another way to get the image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is you can't use dynamic string for `require` (check the link in Muhammad Mehar's comment for detail), thus you need to store all `require`d images into an array:

```
const images = [
  require('../img/1.png'),
  require('../img/2.png'),
  ...
  require('../img/726.png'),
];

loadImage(number){
  return <Image source={images[number-1]} />
}
```

Of course you can generate the code lines for the array and copy it to the editor to save time.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! Indeed I finally generated a function which is basically a switch/case with 726 entries to require each image when I need it. I'm very surprised there is no way to do it in an easier way but I guess there is a good reason

Answer (score -1):

Switch case is garbage.
Use template literals.

```
loadImage(number){
  imgPath = `../img/${number.toString()}.png` 
  return(
    <Image source={require(imgPath)} />
)
```

Comment: `require` needs string constant.