# Dynamically access variable inside `require` keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, require

I want to implement a async require so i am using a variable inside require keyword that is not working, But if i supply string it works as usual.
I want a help to set it working properly

```
const asyncRequire = (path) => {
    try {
        return require(path);
    } catch (error) {
        LogUtils.error('Dynamic Require failed', error);
        return null;
    }
};
```

This `require(path)`is not working.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: remember, path must be relative to actually where you're calling `require` from, not `asyncRequire`

Comment: Yeah, it's relative but the require eywork is not taking varibale as an argument

Comment: Please use tags properly, tagging a question as both `node.js` and `react` reduces your chances of getting a proper solution for your environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use dynamic paths in `require` currently. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names/30868078#30868078) answer.

Check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391) issue also for discussions and possible alternatives.