# Load a set of images from a directory in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a group of images in a directory and I want to add the paths to an array in **react native**.

The image names are 1.png, 2.png, 3.png... 20.png

The following is the method I currently use

```
 const images = [require('../assets/1/1.png'),
                 require('../assets/1/2.png'),
                 require('../assets/1/3.png'),
                 ...
                 require('../assets/1/20.png'),];
```

This is possible when there is a limited number of images. In some cases I might have to add 300 images. So is there an easy way to do this?

I tried adding in a loop but it does not work.

```
    for (let i = 1; i < 300; i++) {
        images.push(require('../assets/1/'+i+'.png'))    
    }
```

**EDIT :** 
 The following error occurs in the above approach,

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Components\IdleLoop.js:Invalid call at line 9: require('../assets/1/' + i + '.png')
    at F:\_work\sampleApp\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:317:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (F:\_work\sampleApp\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:75:24)
    at _next (F:\_work\sampleApp\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:95:9)
```

Comment: Is there any error, when you use for loop?

Comment: The question is why do you need to do so? anywhere you need to show the images just set the src to the needed path

Comment: @KaushikRadadiya Yes there is an error. I will add it to the question.

Comment: Check this : https://dev.to/emilios1995/dynamic-imports-in-react-native-9k5

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I need it because I uses an `ImageSequence`. There I need set of images to animate.

Comment: Why are you using **require** there is no need just add file path as a string.

Comment: @KaushikRadadiya It wont work, I tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know because React Native applications are statically bundled on build time, `require`d assets are linked in advanced therefore there isn't a way to load them dynamically on runtime. I've ran into the same problem and gave up on that and ended up linking everything manually/statically.

For more information you might want to check out [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names), which concludes the same.