# How do I place state inside a string?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to place my state inside a string, as I am rendering an image depending on which 'type' state is.

I have tried Template literals below:

```
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = {
   type: 'cafe'
 }
```

And in my component:

```
 <Image
      source={require(        
 `../../../assets/icons/${this.state.type}.png`)}
 />
```

I would expect the outcome above to be:

```
 <Image
      source={require('../../../assets/icons/cafe.png')}
 />
```

Comment: The `require` needs to be static.  You could possibly require both and then switch between what they resolve to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using template literals with `this.state` should be fine for string interpolation but `react-native`'s `Image` does not support dynamic paths for `require`. See the documentation at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

Instead you can `require` all the images at the module level and use the `state` to select the appropriate one.

```
const images = {
  cafe: require('../../../assets/icons/cafe.png'),
  // .. other images here
};

...

<Image source={images[this.state.type]} />
```