# React: Image source INVALID prop (source uses string with adress to the image)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In the Image Block the Source uses the array of string from PlayerInfo. 
PlayerInfo consists string of arrays:

```js
require('../img/player1.jpg')
require('../img/player2.jpg')
```

In the image below I use the

```
(image source= {item.item})
```

--> so that it looks like this

```
(image source = require('../img/player1.jpg'))
```

BUT this seems to not work. What do I have to change inside the source to make the images appear?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDHfL.jpg)

Comment: you cant use dynamic imports for image , thats a limitation in react -native . either host it in a server and pass the uri or check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `<Image>` you should give it a static resource. So the problem is here:

```
[...playerInfo, `require('../img/player${numPlayer}.jpg')`]
```

you can implement the same functionality using a code like this:

```
const playerInfo=[
  {
    "index" : "1",
    "item" : require('../img/player1.jpg'),
  },
  {
    "index" : "2",
    "item" : require('../img/player2.jpg'),
  }
]
```

But I think if you have a large list of players creating a customized image component will come more handy:

```
class CustomizedImage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props); 
    } 

    render() { 
       return (
         <Image source= {this.props.source} 
                resizeMode="contain" 
                style={{ height: this.props.height, width: this.props.width}} /> 
       ); 
    } 
}
```

then use it like this:

```
<CustomizedImage source= {require(`../img/player${numPlayer}.jpg`)} 
                 height={100}
                 width={100}             
/>
```

I haven't run this but it should work properly. Also creating your own customized components is a good way for developing an app, since you can change your package (for example use 'react-native-fast-image' instead) or other configs whenever you wish.