# React native states error in return function

Tags: react-native

```
export default function CardImageExample (props) {

  const [path,setpath] = React.useState("'../collections/download-0.jpg'")

  function change(){
    console.log(path)

    if(path == "'../collections/download.jpg'"){
      setpath("'../collections/download-0.jpg'")
    }
    else{
      setpath("'../collections/download.jpg'")
    }
  }

    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Card style={{height: 240, width: 280, alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <CardItem bordered button onPress={change}>
            **<Image source={require(path)} />**
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
}
```

the path variable does not work but if i use the path directly it works..
Please save

Comment: What do you mean with `does not work`? What do you expect to happen? What does actually happen? Is there an error? Can you share logs/stack traces?

Comment: error: bundling failed: components\card.js: components\card.js:Invalid call at line 23: require(path)  this is the error when i use path variable in the require() function. But when i use the actual path i.e '../collections/download-0.jpg' , it works fine. i want to use the path variable

Comment: And what is line 23 of card.js?

Comment: <image> tag line is 23

Comment: Is the program executed in the correct directory?

Comment: yes it is, i think there is some syntax error

Answer (score 0):

try passing require inside the path state and then in Image source pass only **path** instead of **require(path)**

you can check this other similar question, I think it will help you:

[React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Comment: glad to help @JatinAgarwal :)