# React Native - cannot import image from path

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following basic react native code:

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Image} from 'react-native';

//images
import login_blueGirl from './assets/images/login_blueGirl.png';


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={login_blueGirl}></Image>
     </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
});

export default App;
```

I'm getting a `Cannot find module './assets/images/login_blueGirl.png'`. When I type `./` VSCode give me however the autocomplete option:

[image]
[image]

Any clue on why this is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Comment: @xdeepakv this doesn't solve the question

Comment: none of the answer ?

Comment: react native is is not server app, app has to require image dynamically, one app loaded.

Answer (score 2):

That's not quite how you're supposed to be importing images, use `require` instead.

```js
const App = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image source={require("./assets/images/login_blueGirl.png")} />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: For some reason this still doesn't load the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the width and height of the image to display it, do this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 80 }} source={require("./assets/images/login_blueGirl.png")}></Image>
    </View>
  );
};
```

or

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imgStyle: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
    }
});

const App = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.imgStyle} source={require("./assets/images/login_blueGirl.png")}></Image>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To import a static file like a `.png` file, you can declare

`const blueGirl = require("assets/images/login_blueGirl.png");`

Then you can use it in an `Image` component

`<Image style={styles.image} source={blueGirl} />`

Also the image is used as a self closing tag you don't have to add another `</Image>` tag.

In order to fully understand how tags and syntax work always check out the official documentation
[React Native API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image)

Comment: I've done it like this and it still doesn't display the image. Moreover when I hover over const blueGirl = require("assets/images/login_blueGirl.png"); VSCode comments that it should be converted to an import which results in the original line with import: https://i.imgur.com/G7jVimY.png

Comment: When you hover on it your default node linter is showing the problem, however, you should add a linting tool for React Native like this one https://medium.com/appstud/setup-eslint-and-prettier-together-for-react-and-react-native-projects-in-visual-studio-code-78772d58358d also please make sure that you set a width and height for the image as well to display it.