# Why this template literals is not working in react native image source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My initial image source is something like this

```
<Image
    style={[styles.iconArea,
            focused ? styles.focusTint : styles.unFocusTint,
        ]}
    source={require(`../assets/Icons/home.png`)}
></Image>
```

So I want to create a function that return different images rather than home image only.

So I create a func like this

```
function something(icon){
    <Image
        style={[styles.iconArea,
                focused ? styles.focusTint : styles.unFocusTint,
            ]}
        source={require(`../assets/Icons/${icon}.png`)}
    ></Image>
}

something("cart")
```

This thing is whenever I tried to run
its giving me syntax error with this message

[image]

What am I doing wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30868078/9787233