# Pass Custom Relative Image source to Image Tag React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a custom component in React Native which contains an Image tag with a custom source to be passed to it. The problem now is, I am getting an error that says `Invalid call at line 17: require(imageSrc)`.

This is my GoalButton component code below:

```js
const GoalButton = ({
  buttonStyle,
  onPress,
  text,
  imageSrc,
  imageStyle,
  textStyle,
}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={buttonStyle}>
        <Image style={imageStyle} source={require(imageSrc)} />
        // Above line is Line 17
        <Text style={textStyle}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

GoalButton.defaultProps = {
  buttonStyle: styles.buttonStyle,
  onPress: () => null,
  imageStyle: styles.imageStyle,
  textStyle: styles.textStyle,
};

export default GoalButton;
```

And I call it from outside like this:

```js
<GoalButton text={'Meal Plan'} imageSrc={'../assets/images/plate.png'} />;
```

My question is, is there a way I can pass a relative image URL to the component and access it without any error like I was using it directly on the Image component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible, you can looked this,

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names#:~:text=The%20only%20allowed%20way%20to%20refer%20to%20an%20image%20in%20the%20bundle%20is%20to%20literally%20write%20require(%27image!name-of-the-asset%27)%20in%20the%20source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names#:%7E:text=The%20only%20allowed%20way%20to%20refer%20to%20an%20image%20in%20the%20bundle%20is%20to%20literally%20write%20require(%27image!name-of-the-asset%27)%20in%20the%20source).

Comment: Funny how I tried this before, didn't work. Now I tried it again and it did! Thanks a lot. Your answer helped :)