# In Javascript, how can I dynamically construct a path within a require()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've got an environment file.

Like the title says, I want to build the path for my images based on the config setup, like so :

```
const images = {
      logo: require(`./${Config.BRAND}/images/logo_${Config.BRAND}.png`)
    };
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: Did you maybe forget the extension? (.png, .jpg, ...)

Comment: If you use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) you can achieve this.

Comment: Dynamic imports is an anti-pattern https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.22.1/docs/rules/no-dynamic-require.md

Comment: @enzo in react-native every image is a module (more or less). It's the official way to load local images: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.

Comment: @Erenn How would this solve the problem? I don't see how this has anything to do with JSharles question.

Comment: @MauriceNino Indeed, I forgot to add the extension in the example, but I've added it in the code.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Does the path actually resolve to anything, if you write it as a static string?

Comment: @MauriceNino Static string works fine. The error I get is : error: assets/index.js: assets/index.js:Invalid call at line 11: require("./" + _reactNativeConfig.default.BRAND + "/images/logo_" + _reactNativeConfig.default.BRAND + ".png")

Comment: Did you print the value of `./${Config.BRAND}/images/logo_${Config.BRAND}.png` to the console? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it logs me the correct string.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using dynamic requires as it has bad consequences.

- Metro bundler will not package unused images and dynamic require makes it hard to detect.
- It is covered in the official documentation: [React Native - Static Image Resources](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources)
- It is also generally not advised by ESLint: [eslint-plugin-import/no-dynamic-require](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.22.1/docs/rules/no-dynamic-require.md)

You can use if-else (or simply ternary) or switch statement to get the image you want to use.

```js
const images = {
  logo: Config.BRAND === 'brand1' ? require(`./brand1/images/logo_brand1.png`) : require(`./brand2/images/logo_brand2.png`);
};
```

Comment: Indeed, this method works fine but the dynamic require would reduce a lot the amount of code.

Comment: I don't think this applies here. Static code analysis is generally not done on images. I would say you can ignore/disable this eslint rule at that position.

Comment: Most likely images would not be copied to bundle because metro bundler will think those images are not used because of dynamic require.

Comment: @MauriceNino actually, metro bundler doesn't copy the unused images to the release build, and dynamic require makes it hard to detect.

Comment: It worked for me. Excellent answer....

Comment: Safe to say, you are right @UgurEren :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names You should however extend your answer to include the reason why it does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Create a .env file in the root of project. Put dynamic brand there.

```
BRAND=Your_dynamic_link
```

install than import dotenv module

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Than you can access that environment

```
const images = {
  logo: require(`./${process.env.BRAND}/images/logo_${process.env.BRAND}.png`)
};
```

Comment: That is actually exactly what I'm doing , but the require does not accept that.

Comment: Can you access the env variable? Weird.