# React Native load an array of sound files

Tags: javascript, react-native

how can I refactor loading 75 mp3 files as follows vs longhand?

```
const numberFiles = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 75; i++) {
  const moduleFile = require(`./sounds/${i + 1}.mp3`);
  numberFiles.push(moduleFile);
}
```

run time keeps telling me

```
 [Error: TransformError App.js: App.js:Invalid call at line 27: require("./sounds/" + (i + 1) + ".mp3")]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - Image Require Module using Dynamic Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names)

Comment: no, I looked that over.  I want to be able to dynamically load a number of required files without having to do it long hand.  I don't know that **require** allows dynamic

Comment: Exactly, it's not possible

Comment: Thanks. I’ll close and request of the RN feature list