React native Expo - Invalid Call TransformError in Image source require

// each bookshelf component runs this, currently i have 2.
export default function Bookshelf({id, title})
{
    const bookshelfData = useBookshelvesStore((state) => state.data)
    var bookCount = bookshelfData[id - 1].books.length // get the count, used to get the image

    function onBookshelfPressed(){
        router.push({
            pathname: './bookshelfItems/'+id,      
        }) 
    }
    return(
        
        <View className='flex mx-5 bg-zinc-800'>
            <Pressable onPress={onBookshelfPressed}>
                <Text className='font-fbold text-white text-xl pt-2 pb-0.5'>{title}</Text>
                <View className={"flex h-32 bg-zinc-900 rounded-xl mb-3"}>
                {
                    bookCount > 0 ? <Image source={require("../assets/icons/bookshelf_icons/"+bookCount+".png")}/> : null // crashing here
                }

                </View>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    );
}


This is the error
components\Bookshelf.tsx: components\Bookshelf.tsx:Invalid call at line 24: require("../assets/icons/bookshelf_icons/" + bookCount + ".png")


When bookCount == 2, it should show ../assets/icons/bookshelf_icons/2.png
It seems that the problem is with var bookCount. If I do something like
"../assets/icons/bookshelf_icons/"+2+".png"

it works but with bookCount it doesnt.
This also works.
var index = 2
require("../assets/icons/bookshelf_icons/"+index+".png") // works


This ended up working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854232/react-native-image-require-module-using-dynamic-names
